# Unwrap UVs preserving seams AND proportional face area?

Tags: uv

I am trying to figure out Blender's UV unwrapping options. I need to preserve seams so that seam borders correspond to UV islands/shells. I also need to preserve proportional face area, so UV face area corresponds to polygon face area, with no stretching.

Ordinary "Unwrap" preserves seams but does not preserve proportional face area.

"Smart UV Project" preserves proportional face area but does not preserve seams. It creates a jillion UV islands.

The best result I've seen so far is "Unwrap" followed by "Minimize Stretch". Is this the best workflow?

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: Hello :). UV unwrapping is often a compromise between number of seams/amount of stretching. Just add more seams :).

Comment: I am very familiar with the best practices of UV unwrapping. My question is, is there a better way of preserving face area and seams? Or is "Unwrap" followed by "Minimize Stretch" the best way? Maya and 3ds Max have one-click solutions that perform this task flawlessly, every time, and are completely bulletproof.